# sha256 + salt помогите с авторизацией

Tags: php, хеширование, sha256

Здравствуйте, у меня возникла проблема показывается ошибку при ошибочном вводе и не входит в личный кабинет.

`Fatal error: Call to undefined function password_verify() in Z:\home\Shkolonik111.ru\www\engine\authorization.php on line 14`

authorization.php

```
<?/*Функция авторизации*/
require 'config.php';
if(isset($_POST['login']))
{   
$name = $_POST['name'];
$passwordFromPost = $_POST['password'];
$hashedPasswordFromDB = 'salt';
$search = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$account['table']."` WHERE 
`".$account['name']."`='$name'");
if(mysql_num_rows($search)!=0)
{
    $user = mysql_fetch_array($search);
    if($user["".$account['pass'].""]==$passwordFromPost)
    {
        setcookie("pass", password_verify($passwordFromPost, 
    $hashedPasswordFromDB).":".$name, time() + 60*100, "/");
        header("Location: ./");
    }
    else
    {
        $info_pass="<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">
    <strong>Ошибка!</strong> Пароль не правильный.
    </div>";
    }

    }
        else
        {
    $info_user = "<div class=\"alert alert-danger\">
     <strong>Ошибка!</strong> Игрок не найден.
    </div>";
        }
    }
    if($_GET["access"]=="exit"){
        setcookie("pass", "", "0", "/");
        header("Location: ./login.php");
    }   
    ?>
```

И сам login.php

```
<form action="" method="POST">
      <div class="form-group">
        <?=$info_user?>
         <br>
<input type="text" required placeholder="Ваш ник-нейм" name="name" 
 class="l- input"><br>
 <br>
<?=$info_pass?>
<input type="password" required placeholder="Ваш 
пароль" name="password" class="l-input margin"> 
<br>
<center><button class="btn btn-l" type="submit" 
name="login">Авторизоваться</button></center>
</div>
</form>
```

Сам не сильно понимаю про хэш. У меня в бд пароль в sha256 + salt. Как мне сделать авторизацию с помощью sha256 и salt? Много чего перепробовал, ничего не помогло.

Comment: Версия php какая?

Comment: PHP VERSION 5.3.13

Comment: Поставьте хотя бы 5.6